# Yii2 sort and filter in GridView with viaTable relation

Tags: gridview, yii2, relation

I can't figure out how filtering and sorting works in Yii2 with relational table.

I have 3 tables because Links can have multiple countries. I figured out how to save it into links_countries table.

```
Links     Countries  LinksCountries
link_id   country    link_id
country              country
```

Links and Countries are connected with this relation in Links model

```
    public function getManyCountries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Countries::className(), ['country' => 'country'])->viaTable('links_countries', ['links_id' => 'links_id']);
    }
```

In in the index.php GridView I have

```
[
                'label' => 'Countries',
                'attribute' => 'linksCountries.country',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    $countries = ArrayHelper::map($model->manyCountries, 'country', 'country_name');
                    return implode(', ', $countries);
                 },
                'format' => 'raw'

            ],
```

which results in such grid

### [image]

As you can see link with ID 1034 has multiple countries but filter is not working this way.
So how to display grid like this?

```
Link ID    Country     Link
1034       Andorra     linkname1
1034       Kosovo      linkname1
```

I tried this relation

```
public function getLinksCountries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LinksCountries::className(), ['links_id' => 'links_id']);
    }
```

and in LinksSearch model

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    //'query' => $query,
    'query' => $this->getLinksCountries(),
]);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that. Everything is displayed and sorting works but with no filter

Comment: all filters are not working?

Comment: Sorry i dont get it. In your example, your gridview is already showing that ID 1034 have 2 countries. Are you trying to change that to 2 separate rows? Or your problem is just the lack of a filter?

Comment: @Clyff I found the solution [here](http://webtips.krajee.com/filter-sort-calculated-related-fields-gridview-yii-2-0/) (Scenario 2). I displayed the grid based on LinksCountries model, so it displayed 2 separate rows for the same ID and getting other values from Links model.

Comment: Yes, that's right. When you have some time, don't forget to post your own answer and accept it. Doing that, makes easier for someone find the solution if facing the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Clyff. Yes, I will post my answer later.

Answer (score 4):

So, the solution was to show grid based on LinksCountries model and getting values from Links model.

**LinksCountries.php**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

class LinksCountries extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'links_countries';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['links_id', 'country'], 'required'],
            [['links_id'], 'integer'],
            [['modified_date', 'created_date'], 'safe'],
            [['country'], 'string', 'max' => 3],
            [['modified_by', 'created_by'], 'string', 'max' => 64]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getManyCountries()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Countries::className(), ['country' => 'country']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Links::className(), ['links_id' => 'links_id']);
    }

    public function getCountryName() {
        return $this->country->country_name;
    }

    public function getLinkName() {
        return $this->links->link;
    }

    public function getShortDescription() {
        return $this->links->short_description;
    }
}
```

**LinksCountriesSearch.php**

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\LinksCountries;

class LinksCountriesSearch extends LinksCountries
{
    public $linkName;
    public $shortDescription;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['links_countries_id', 'links_id'], 'integer'],
            [['country', 'modified_by', 'modified_date', 'created_by', 'created_date', 'linkName', 'shortDescription'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {

        $query = LinksCountries::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['linkName'] = [
            'asc' => ['links.link' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['links.link' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['shortDescription'] = [
            'asc' => ['links.short_description' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['links.short_description' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $query->joinWith('links');
        $query->joinWith('manyCountries');     

        $this->load($params);

        if(!$this->validate()){
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'links_countries_id' => $this->links_countries_id,
            'links.links_id' => $this->links_id,
            'modified_date' => $this->modified_date,
            'created_date' => $this->created_date,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'countries.country_name', $this->country])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'links.link', $this->linkName])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'links.short_description', $this->shortDescription])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modified_by', $this->modified_by])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'created_by', $this->created_by]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use common\models\Countries;

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
                'attribute' => 'links_id',
                'width'=>'50px',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'country',
                'value' => 'manyCountries.country_name',
                'vAlign'=>'middle',
                'width'=>'200px',
                'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                    'filter'=> ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()->orderBy('country_name')->asArray()->all(), 'country_name', 'country_name'),
                    'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                        'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true],
                    ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Select country'],
                'format'=>'raw',
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'linkName',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return Html::a($model->linkName, $model->linkName, ['target'=>'_blank']);
                },
            ],
            'shortDescription',
    ],

]);
```

Comment: Undefined class constant 'FILTER_SELECT2'

Comment: @glyph you need to use use kartik\grid\GridView instead of Yii2 GridView

Answer (score 1):

For adding Filter (and sorting)  functionalities  in your modelSearch you should add the related field to the dataProvider  setting sort part (*the default model's fields have filter by default while for  related fields you must add the filter using setSort*)

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

$dataProvider->setSort([
  'attributes' => [
      'your_new_attribute' => [
         'asc' => ['your_related_table_name.your_field' => SORT_ASC],
         'desc' => ['your_related_table_name.your_field' => SORT_DESC],
          'label' => 'Your_label',
          'default' => SORT_ASC
      ],  
  .....
```

and for adding defaultOrder you simply add the condition for this

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
  'attributes' => [
      'your_new_attribute' => [
         'asc' => ['your_related_table_name.your_field' => SORT_ASC],
         'desc' => ['your_related_table_name.your_field' => SORT_DESC],
          'label' => 'Your_label',
          'default' => SORT_ASC
      ],  
  'defaultOrder' => [ 'your_new_attribute' => SORT_DESC ],
   ........
```

Comment: TY works fine!
I just add some notes for issue below:
to add general sort by 'your_new_attribute' add this in attributes section
'defaultOrder' => [
    'your_new_attribute' => SORT_DESC
]